# How do you create a Flutter bottom navigation with a top line on active menu item?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following Flutter bottom navigation[image] bar

And I would like to add a top-line or boarder for active items like so

[image]

Is that even possible, my code is straight forward.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _tabs[_tabIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff546481),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        currentIndex: _tabIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _tabIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'HOME',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.history_outlined),
            label: 'HISTORY',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
            label: 'PROFILE',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined),
            label: 'SETTINGS',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a TabBar instead of a BottomNavigationBar using a custom decoration:

```dart
class TopIndicator extends Decoration {
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
    return _TopIndicatorBox();
  }
}

class _TopIndicatorBox extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    Paint _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.cyan
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..isAntiAlias = true;

    canvas.drawLine(offset, Offset(cfg.size!.width + offset.dx, 0), _paint);
  }
}
```

Then pass the decoration to the TapBar using `TapBar(indicator: TopIndicator ...)`.

[image: tabbar]

To use the TabBar as the `Scaffold.bottomNavigationBar`, you will most likely want to wrap it in a `Material` to apply a background color:

```dart
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Material(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: TabBar(
      indicator: TopIndicator(),
      tabs: const <Widget>[
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), text: 'HOME'),
        ...
      ],
    ),
  ),
  ...
)
```

Thanks [Ara Kurghinyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530959/1584915) for the original idea.

Answer (score 1):

there are some packages can achieve this effect:

[titled_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/titled_navigation_bar)

```
bottomNavigationBar: TitledBottomNavigationBar(
  currentIndex: 2, // Use this to update the Bar giving a position
  onTap: (index){
    print("Selected Index: $index");
  },
  items: [
      TitledNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Home'), icon: Icons.home),
      TitledNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Search'), icon: Icons.search),
      TitledNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Bag'), icon: Icons.card_travel),
      TitledNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Orders'), icon: Icons.shopping_cart),
      TitledNavigationBarItem(title: Text('Profile'), icon: Icons.person_outline),
  ]
)
```

[bottom_indicator_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_indicator_bar)

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<BottomIndicatorNavigationBarItem> items = [
    BottomIndicatorNavigationBarItem(icon: Icons.home),
    BottomIndicatorNavigationBarItem(icon: Icons.search),
    BottomIndicatorNavigationBarItem(icon: Icons.settings),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Indicator Bottom Bar"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomIndicatorBar(
        onTap: (index) => {},
        items: items,
        activeColor: Colors.teal,
        inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
        indicatorColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but not looking at using any packages for something like this, actually the bottom_indicator_bar package looks pretty good will try that

Comment: This is no good no text under the icon might need to fork the repo

Comment: Any solution because i've asked the same question, and not looking forward to using a package >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072981/flutter-have-a-line-on-top-of-the-bottom-navigation-bar-witch-goes-to-the-select

Comment: if you found the answer i would really appreciate if you would help

Answer (score 0):

The `bottomNavigationBar` can be any `Widget`.
Here is how you can create that - you will need to declare the list of names to use (`_tabs`) and the selected index (`_indexTab`)

```
FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 1 / 12,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ..._tabs.map((name) {
              final index = _tabs.indexOf(name);
              final isSelected = _indexTab == index;
              final asset = index == 0 ? isSelected ? Asset.home : Asset.homeLight
                  : index == 1 ? isSelected ? Asset.returns : Asset.returnsLight
                  : isSelected ? Asset.account : Asset.accountLight;
              return Expanded(
                child: WidgetAction(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    radius: Spacing.unit * 10,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: FractionallySizedBox(
                            widthFactor: 1 / 2,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(Spacing.unit * 10),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(Spacing.unit * 10),
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                height: Spacing.unit / 3,
                                color: isSelected ? RGB.purpleBright : Colors.transparent,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                asset
                            ),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: Spacing.unit * 0.5
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              name,
                              style: isSelected ? Style.semibold10 : Style.semibold10TabGrey,
                            ),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: Spacing.unit * 0.5
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _indexTab = index;
                      });
                    }
                ),
              );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Column(
              children: [
                pageIndex == 2
                    ? Container(
                        height: 5.w,
                        width: 35.h,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.teal,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(
                                3,
                              ),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(3)),
                        ),
                        // height: 5,
                        // width: 35,
                      )
                    : SizedBox(
                        height: 5.w,
                        width: 35.h,
                      ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 4.h,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 25.h,
                    width: 25.w,
                    // alignment: Alignment.lerp(
                    //     Alignment.bottomLeft, Alignment.bottomRight, 1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      // color: Colors.red,
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                        iconSize: 25,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4),
                        visualDensity:
                            const VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                        enableFeedback: false,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            pageIndex = 2;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: pageIndex == 2
                            ? Image.asset(
                                'assets/icons/icons8-alarm-50.png',
                                height: 24.h,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                // size: 35.sm,
                              )
                            : Image.asset(
                                'assets/icons/icons8-alarm-50.png',
                                color: Colors.black,
                                // size: 35.sm,
                              )),
                  ),
                ),
                pageIndex == 2
                    ? Container(
                        height: 15.h,
                        width: 60.w,
                        alignment: Alignment.lerp(
                            Alignment.centerLeft, Alignment.centerRight, 0.75),
                        child: Text(
                          'Reminder',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(),
              ],
            ),
```